# How can I find information regarding a domain that does no longer exist?

Tags: dns, lookup, history, registrar

Does anybody knows a way to find whois records for a domain that does no longer exist?
I had a domain name in the past pet-pal.co.il, I changed it to petpal.co.il and now the first domain name no longer exist, but I would like to see in what year I registered it, is there a way to see history lookup or something?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing standardized that retains such information. You'll have to go to secondary sources like `archive.org` (if it was a web site), or contact the registrar/registry and ask if they keep old information around.

Comment: Thanks, although after alot of searches I did found many sites that provide such information, but only for very specific domain name extensions (such as .com only etc), so I had to give up evantually ;p